# Grouping my data in the view - nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I grab some data from postgresql DB and want to display it in a view, simple enough  as below

**routes.js**

```
app.get('/fixtures', async (req, res) => {
  const fixtures = await queries.getFixtures();
  res.render('fixtures', { fixtures });
});

fixtures returns
[ { id: 27,
    home_team: 'Chelsea',
    away_team: 'Liverpool',
    league_name: 'English Premiership',
  },
  { id: 25,
    home_team: 'Man Utd',
    away_team: 'Everton',
    league_name: 'English Premiership',
  },
  { id: 30,
    home_team: 'Istanbul Basaksehir',
    away_team: 'Akhisar Belediye',
    league_name: 'Turkish Super Lig',
  }
]
```

**getFixtures();**

```
async function getFixtures() {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await pool.query('select * from fixtures ORDER BY league_name ASC');
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error Occurred', e);
  }
  return response.rows;
}
```

**fixtures.ejs**

```
<% fixtures.forEach((fixture) => { %>
   <p><%=fixture.league_name %></p>
   <p><%= fixture.home_team %> vs <%= fixture.away_team %> </p>
<% }) %>
```

So the above will output

```
English Premiership
Chelsea vs Liverpool

English Premiership
Man Utd v Everton

Turkish Super Lig
Istanbul Basaksehir vs Akhisar Belediye
```

However I would like to group my fixtures by league and would prefer to have the view output as

```
English Premiership
Chelsea vs Liverpool
Man Utd v Everton

Turkish Super Lig
Istanbul Basaksehir vs Akhisar Belediye
```

How do I go about achieving this? Is this something at DB query level or something I do in the view? (though probably not the best place to keep logic I guess)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what tools/libs you are using but without depending on any libs/tools you can do it using vanilla `JavaScript`. For example, check the following code:

```
app.get('/fixtures', async (req, res) => {

    const fixtures = await queries.getFixtures();

    const grouped = groupByLeagueName(fixtures);

    res.render('fixtures', { fixtures: grouped });
});
```

Then, implement the `groupByLeagueName` function like this:

```
function groupByLeagueName(fixtures) {

    return fixtures.reduce((result, item) => {

        result[item.league_name] = result[item.league_name] || [];

        result[item.league_name].push(item);

        return result;

    }, {});
}
```

Then in your view you may loop it something like this:

```
<% for (let leagueName in fixtures) { %>

    <p><%= leagueName %></p>

    <% fixtures[leagueName].forEach((match, key) => { %>

        <p><%= match.home_team %> vs <%= match.away_team %> </p>

    <% }) %>

<% } %>
```

Comment: Thats great, thank you so much, learned some things there too